# Difference between GaugeService and CounterService at Springboot Actuator

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an example project to use GaugeService and CounterService,

I have realized that GaugeService keeps last value submitted, but I am expecting it will be calculated in a way of rolling append.

So with this case GaugeService threads like CounterService.
GaugeService  has only submit() method exposed no other configuration settings found.

What is the difference between GaugeService and CounterService?

Answer (score 3):

You answered your question yourself in your post:

**GaugeService.submit()** overwrites the last value with the new one. It's just like a speedometer in your car, which only shows your current speed. You can use GaugeService for monitoring the current number of active sessions or threads or the like.

**CounterService.increment()** increments the current value by one. You can use CounterService to count things like how many sessions were created or how many errors occured in your application or something like that.

Comment: I was expecting GaugeService has a rollinaverage algorithm in built. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Both are for recording your own metrics. For example, number of bids for a property, bid value, etc.

CounterService is used to increase (by 1), decrease (by 1) or reset an existing counter.

GaugeService is used to publish updates. Named gauges can be generated at runtime. These gauges can be used for sensors, running-values, etc to something/someone else which/who monitors these values.

Comment: so there is only logical diffence between them, but both do same thing